# Unable to access the IP address of Docker container running a React client

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

After running `docker-compose up --build`, the container running my React client is inaccessible. The following is a log for the output:

```
client_1      | ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.18.0.4/
client_1      | ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
client_1      | ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
client_1      | ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
client_1      | Starting the development server...
```

What's strange is that after the above is displayed, my terminal shows me warnings and errors from my React code. When I try accessing the IP address, `http://172.18.0.4/` in my browser, it doesn't load at all. I've tried `localhost:3000` which is Reacts default port and nothing worked.

I have tried looking into the actual container by running, `docker-run -it container-id sh`, and all the files necessary for the client to run is there. I'm not too sure what's wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Below are my development Dockerfile and Docker Compose file.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres_password
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./server
    # To have a reference to local file system
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./server:/app      
    environment:
      - PGUSER=postgres
      - PGHOST=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres_password
      - PGPORT=5432
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  client:
    stdin_open: true
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./client
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app
  rtmpserver:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./rtmpserver
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./rtmpserver:/app
```

**Dockerfile.dev**

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm","run", "start"]
```

**EDIT:**
I have ran the following command, `docker run -p 3000:3000 -v /app/node_modules -v "$(pwd):/app" container-id`, and got the following result.

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /app/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Which doesn't make any sense since all the files are present in the container..

Comment: Did you try to forward the appropriate ports?

Comment: @DanielMann Hey, I'm kind of new to Docker and networking haha. What do you mean by that?

Comment: As with most things, the best place to start is the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose

Comment: @DanielMann Couldn't I just add "EXPOSE PORT-NUM" in the docker dev file and it would be the same thing?

Comment: Your `volumes:` and `docker run -v` options are hiding basically everything the Dockerfiles do; I'm not surprised you don't get consistent results trying to run the containers via different paths.  I'd recommend just deleting these options entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the container IP (http://172.18.0.4/) to access to your service from outside docker network. You need to expose your port in Docker file then access using localhost:3000.

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm","run", "start"]
```

Add the port mapping in docker-compose.yml

```
ports:
  - "3000:3000"
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Ya, I have that just done that. Now for some reason, my localhost:3000 is being used up by another project. I tried to kill the port and run it up again, but it still opens the old one.

Comment: you can map to another port if you have a confilt "4000:3000"

Comment: If I do "4000:3000", that would be for the docker compose file? I could just leave the the dockerfile as "EXPOSE 3000"?

Comment: I have another question, when I run the command, docker run -p 3000:3000 -v /app/node_modules -v "$(pwd):/app" container-id, do you happen to know why I got the error message I got above?

Comment: Is ./app/package.json exists on your host ?